# Python - API request does not refresh

Tags: python

```
import requests
from time import sleep

r = requests.get('https://testnet.bitmex.com/api/v1/trade?symbol=.BVOL24H&count=1&columns=price&reverse=true')
data = r.json()
volatility = r.json()[0]['price']


def loop():
    while True:
        print(data)
        print(volatility)
        sleep(10)


loop()
```

I'm trying to use this data for my project but when I make this API request it keeps returning the same value.

The API refreshes its data every 5 minutes. (12:35:00, 12:40:00 etc.)

How do I make sure my function always has the most recent data?

Comment: You need to make the request inside the loop.

Comment: You are not updating the `data` and `volatility` variables, so no, you'll not see any changes. You need to make the request each time, in the loop, not once before the loop.

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick answer guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to request new data in each run of the loop.

```
import requests
from time import sleep

def loop():
    while True:
        r = requests.get('https://testnet.bitmex.com/api/v1/trade?symbol=.BVOL24H&count=1&columns=price&reverse=true')
        data = r.json()
        volatility = r.json()[0]['price']
        print(data)
        print(volatility)
        sleep(10)


loop()
```

Comment: I have one more question. Is there a way for the volatility variable to be called by another script while it's running in a loop in this script? If I try without the loop I have the same problem as above, it won't update the variables. Would I have to use threading or something similar?

Comment: You can do it the otherway arround. Call the other script or more precisly a method from the other script in the loop and give it the volality as a parameter.